# Alert Notification in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to make a notification like line notification. I have tried using alert but it doesn't work. can someone help me for my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by line notification? Have you tried searching for any tutorials?

Comment: line notification do you means snackbar?

Comment: i want to show alert notification. i have read tutorials, but i don't find my problem solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for notification that will be sent even if your app is not running in foreground , [This example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm)  will give you brief idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you looking for this.**

[image]

you can create it like this [Full tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/)

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Welcome to Snackbar notification", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you create a alert dialog

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Alert")
    .setMessage("Hi, This is alert dialog")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // do somthing
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            dismiss();
        }
    })
    .show();
```